# find all my changes in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to see all my changes in the Gerrit. How can I do that? In other words, in perforce I can see a list of all the change lists that I submitted in the GUI. I want to do the same using Gerrit or Git.

Answer (score 5):

In gerrit, type in the search:

```
owner:<your user>
```

gerrit 2.6 and above also supports this shorthand syntax (assuming you're logged in):

```
owner:self
```

In git:

```
git log --author=<your username>
```